# Notation -- What does "Gauss" brackets mean

Tags: notation, normal-distribution

In a paper I'm trying to understand, from a time series $x(1),x(2),\ldots,x(n)$ a new set of time series is created:

$$x^m_k=x(m),x(m+k),x(m+2k),...,x\left(m+\left[ \frac{n-m}{k}\right]k\right) \:\:\:\: ; \:\:\:\: (m=1,2,\ldots,k)$$

where the square brackets $[]$ denote "the Gauss' notation"

What does "the Gauss' notation" mean?  Can someone explicitly define it please.

Answer (score 8):

The Gauss bracket is another name/notation for the floor function $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$, i.e. $[x]=\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the greatest integer not exceeding $x$. It is also called the integer part of $x$.