# Extract integer part of a number

Tags: fractional-part

I want to extract the integer part of number.

For example, I have the number 2.754 and the expected result would be 2.

Can i do it in a mathematical way?

Comment: Greatest integer function

Comment: Yes: $\lfloor2.754\rfloor=2$.

Comment: Occasionally also $[x]$ as Gauß brackets, see the inverse question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/276456/115115

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a mathematical way is a pretty vague term.

Consider the tangent function $\tan(x)$ and the usual branch of its inverse, $\arctan(x)$, from $\mathbb R$ to $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$.

Then with appropriate scalings and shiftings

$$f(x)=\frac1\pi\arctan\left(\tan\left(\pi\left(x+\frac12\right)\right)\right)+\frac12$$

is a sawtooth signal of period $1$, i.e. the fractional part of $x$.

[image]

Then $x-f(x)$ is the integer part.

This definition doesn't work for integers though :(

Comment: what if you take limit x tends to z of your final function, to get the integer part of the real number z?  That would be a mathematical expression that doesn't resort to using the convenience of the computer-programming  like function 'floor'.  i'm really impressed by this, I was trying stuff with arcsin etc but it only worked for some numbers

Comment: @Cato: $\sin/\arcsin$ and $\cos/\arccos$ combinations will end-up in a continuous function, so they are forever unable to extract the fractional part. Of course you can use the left-side limit of the function at integer numbers, but that looks like an "if" test requiring... the floor function.

Comment: if use int detection https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/339510/mathematical-way-of-determining-whether-a-number-is-an-integer/1598552#1598552 and 'if' function https://youtu.be/KAdKCgBGK0k?list=PLnI9xbPdZUAmUL8htSl6vToPQRRN3hhFp&t=313 then may build for integers

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is the floor function, $f(x)=\lfloor x\rfloor$. For a real number $a$, the integer part of $a$ is denoted $\lfloor a\rfloor$ (i.e. the floor of $a$).

Edit: Note that this notation is given as \lfloor x \rfloor, where \lfloor is the left side of the floor (i.e. \lfloor=$\lfloor$) and \rfloor is the right side of the floor (i.e. \rfloor=$\rfloor$).